# Moving a shed for clearance

Tags: construction, shed, building

My building inspector says my shed is too close to the property line (due to the gable overhang) so I need to move it forward about a foot or two.  It's a framed floor on solid concrete blocks, but there is a enough of an incline that I can't just take it off the blocks and roll it on the ground.

As I see it, if I lift the shed on either side, I could  add some addition 2x6 runners that run perpendicular to the permanent runners that would serve as a base for rolling on.  Then lift the shed back and front to insert rollers (PVC pipe), I should be able to roll it forward enough to satisfy my requirement.

Any issues with this approach?  Other ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the black metal fence that you're moving away from, right?

Comment: PVC pipe may not be the best choice of roller. You may find it squished flat. If the blocks are level and you have not bolted into them, you can probably just jack up to put a slippery layer in place (two sheets of plastic) on the blocks and set new blocks at the end point and PULL if it's not too awfully heavy. Otherwise steel pipe is a better choice of roller.

Comment: or pieces of smooth round bar,  you pay more for the hole than for solid steel.

Comment: See also [this offsite post.](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/moving-a-shed.703981/).

Comment: I'm moving away from the wood fence.  I would think steel pipe would bite into the wood runners, preventing it from rolling, wouldn't it?

Comment: wood is pretty tough, and that shed looks fairly light. the rollers will likely mark the wood, but won't sink in.

Comment: Rather than PVC pipe, consider some rebar rods as rollers. Much smaller, less lift, won't collapse.